I'm getting a 403.7 on a website when I hit the status page
I'm getting a 403.7 on a website(WCFService) when I hit the status page. How do I find out which cert is missing?
SSL settings on the directory of the status page -> Client certificates is set to 'Accept' and 'Require SSL' is unchecked.
Not sure how to find out what I'm missing.

Compared the cert store against a working server and I can't seem to find any missing certs; I compared Personal, Trusted root, Intermediate, Trusted Publishers, Trusted People.
Compared the output of openssl s_client -connect :443 -prexit between the working and non-working and they are identical
Compared the cipher suites, FIPS
Ran wireshark; I'm seeing TLS negotiation with Client Hello, Server Hello
No errors logged in the event viewer on the server
I have exhausted all my options, not sure how to proceed further. Appreciate any inputs.



Is a static HTML site working or not? That can help you rule out WCF. 2) If this is just WCF related, enable WCF tracing to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing


@LexLi A static html is also throwing a 403.7 error

Try to check "Require SSL" and switch to "Require" client certificate. That test result will matter a lot on determing the cause.

@LexLi same error, 403.7

Then you will have to start from your HTTP client/browser, as it didn't send out client certificate when the server side requested it (you didn't yet verify that before as you were testing server side TLS, not mutual TLS) and you might not yet configure a client certificate properly. This is not a server side issue based on the tests so far.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403.7 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
